# How to prevent OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have an app which shows someone's images in SkyD.. oh OneDrive!

This is the scenario: from `MainPage.xaml` passes `imageId` and goes to `ImagePage.xaml`. then from inside `ImagePage.xaml` can go deep to a new `ImagePage.xaml` and so on.

`ImagePage.xaml` has one big image like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="12"/>
```

The problem is that when it goes deeper, at some point hits memory limit and exits.

The question, how to prevent `OutOfMemoryException`? I think of a way to unload the page before going deeper or something. thanks.

**Update:** from inside `ImagePage`:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ImagePage.xaml?Id=" + id, UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Post the code that "goes to" another/new Page.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Nothing special, with NavigationService. updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you navigate to a new page, the previous one is kept in memory. If you keep doing that, you'll eventually run out of memory, as you did.

In your case, I think the best solution is to rethink your page flow. Basically, instead of navigating every time to a new instance of your page, stay in the same page and display the new picture. Keep also track of the requested pictures. This way, when the user press the back button, you can check if there's a picture in the history and display it back instead of going back to the previous page.

To summarize, you first need to store the pictures history. A Stack is perfect for that purpose:

```
private Stack<string> History { get; set; }
```

When you need to display a new picture (where you previously had a navigation to ImagePage.xaml), add the previous picture to the history and display the new one:

```
this.History.Push(oldPicture);
// Load the new picture
```

Then, in the OnBackKeyPressed event, cancel the navigation if the history isn't empty. Otherwise, retrieve the latest entry and display it:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.History.Count > 0)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        var picture = this.History.Pop();
        // Display the picture
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks @Kookiz. Just as a short question, if it had to go to different pages deeper what should I do? any tips?

Comment: @user3293835 I'd say, override the `OnNavigatedFrom` event of the page and set the source of all your pictures to null to free the memory, then reload the pictures in the `OnNavigatedTo` event